# Multipeer Connectivity send and receive NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I'm looking to send and receive an NSManagedObject through the multipeer connectivity framework.

```
class MyObject: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var children: NSSet
```

}

I've managed to send strings and dictionaries, but I need to send an NSManagedObject with an NSSet. Is this possible?

Here's what I've tried:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(nsmanagedobject)

    if session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {

        var error: NSError?
        if !session.sendData(data,toPeers: session.connectedPeers, withMode: .Reliable, error: &error){

            println("SEND ERROR:")
            println(error)

        }

    } else {

        println("NO PEERS CONNECTED!")

    }

func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!) {

    NSLog("%@", "didReceiveData: \(data.length) bytes")

    let nsmanagedobject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! MyObject

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with sending an `NSManagedObject` to a different device is that it has been persisted to Core Data on the source device, but cannot simply be deserialized and inserted into the Persistent Store of the target.

I would suggest serializing the objects into `NSDictionary`, sending that data, and then implementing a find-or-create to correctly insert new Managed Objects on your target device.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.  A NSManagedObject is more than just a storage for data it also has a state machine inside of it.

To send data like that you will need to convert it to a more primitive form, arrays, dictionaries, etc.